# How can I access a portion of the state in a reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, reducers

In my case I have a reducer that is a filter configuration and instead of initializing it with an object

```
initial_state = {ditance: 2, showMan: false ...}
```

I want those values to take them from the store because the user has logged in and those values are already in the bbdd of firebase firestore,

I am using the library `react-redux-firestore` and that information is already in another reducer. The problem is that if I use the static `initial_state` when I kill the application it is no longer synchronized with what is in the database.

So what I ask is that if there is any way to be able to take in a reduce the portion of a state that there is in another reduce to generate the new state. I've seen that you can send an action or something like that but I'm looking for another way to do it, if possible .

Answer (score 0):

if data is in another reducer, you can get the value and pass it with action when you call it.

but if it's in the same reducer, you pass two parameters essentially

```
const reducer = (state = initial_state, action) = > {
    switch (action.type){
        case actionType.TOGGLE_SHOWMAN:
            return { ...state, showMan: ! state.showMan };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**so you can access previous state by calling state inside the reducer**